# REGEXP returning false on special characters

Tags: php, regex, letter

I'm not too good in regexp but hoping someone could explain better to me, I found this in the code that I debug. I wonder why I always got false on this scenario.

I know `\p{L}` matches a single code point in the category "letter". `0-9` is numeric.

```
$regExp = /^\s*
     (?P([0-2]?[1-9]|[12]0|3[01]))\s+
     (?P\p{L}+?)\s+
     (?P[12]\d{3})\s*$/i;

    $value = '12 Février 2015' ;
    $matches = array();

    $match = preg_match($regExp, $value, $matches);
```

Additional information, I have come up with this:

```
$match = preg_match("/^\s*(?P<monthDay>([0-2]?[1-9]|[12]0|3[01]))\s+(?P<monthNameFull>\p{L}+?)\s+(?P<yearFull>[12]\d{3})\s*$/i", "18 Février 2015");
var_dump($match); //It will print int(0).
```

But if the value is `18 February 2015`, it will print int(1). Why is that so? It is suppose to return 1 in both values because `\p{L}` will accept unicode characters.

Comment: did you paste the regex in there twice or something?

Comment: The (?P...) construct matches previously named groups, but I don't see any named groups. Are you trying to match a date of the format '12 Fevrier 2015' ?

Comment: Hi Brian, No thats all of the regex being used.

Comment: @user2036161 , Yes. There are some cases too where the regex will be changed depending on the desired format of the user.

Comment: Sorry, just realized the regexp was paste twice. I have it corrected. I looked over thru this website http://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html and its helpful. I'm starting to understand little by little

Comment: Always use the `usD` flags by multiline unicode regex...

Comment: And forget `(?P<name>pattern)` it is for named capturing groups, but you never give a name to them (at least not in your first regex), so use simply `(pattern)` instead of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a fix, use /u instead of /i.

```
$match = preg_match("/^\s*(?P<monthDay>([0-2]?[1-9]|[12]0|3[01]))\s+(?P<monthNameFull>\p{L}+?)\s+(?P<yearFull>[12]\d{3})\s*$/u", "18 Février 2015");
var_dump($match); //It will print int(1).
```

Thanks all for all the help

Comment: Well, I've given you this answer 1 hour ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
$regExp = '/^\s*(?P<y>([0-2]?[1-9]|[12]0|3[01]))\s+(?P<m>\p{L}+?)\s+(?P<d>[12]\d{3})\s*$/usD';

$value = '12 Février 2015';
$matches = array();

$match = preg_match($regExp, $value, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

You always have to use `<name>` with the `(?P` unless you want an error... And by unicode multiline strings you need the `usD` flags. It is easy to remember, its like USA dollar...

Comment: u = unicode, s&D = multiline (so the ^ and $ are the beginning and the end of the whole string and not just the actual line)

Answer (score 0):

No named groups are needed, and the syntax for them seems to be wrong anyway. So this cleaned-up version should work:

`/^
  \s*([0-2]?[1-9]|[12]0|3[01])\s+
  \p{L}+?\s+
  [12]\d{3}\s*
$/i`

The pattern for the day of the month would also be more intelligible as:

`(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])`

Comment: Hi Brian, that doesn't work still. It always return false. Now, I have come up with this regExp /^\s*(?P<monthDay>([0-2]?[1-9]|[12]0|3[01]))\s+(?P<monthNameFull>\p{L}+?)\s+(?P<yearFull>[12]\d{3})\s*$/i , isn't this suppose to return true on preg_match if value is "18 Février 2015" ?

Comment: @user1149244: You don't need the named groups. They're helpful if you are going to use them in code after the match, though. I think the real problem remaining with mine is just the flags, as the others have mentioned. Use `u` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `u` modifier for unicode:

```
$regExp = /^\s*
   (?P<monthDay>([0-2]?[1-9]|[12]0|3[01]))\s+
   (?P<monthNameFull>\p{L}+?)\s+
   (?P<yearFull>[12]\d{3})\s*$/u;
//                      here __^
```

The `i` modifier is not mandatory, `\p{L}` is case insensitive.

Comment: What's `(?P...)` without a name or referenced group name?

Comment: @BrianStephens: I've just taken OP's regex as is. Fixed.